# How to add a class and have thumb option in one line with slim

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-applications, slim-lang

I have this code written in slim.

```
= link_to collaborator.user
  = user_image_of collaborator.user.avatar, thumb: true, class: "ui avatar image carouselCollaboratorsImage"
```

I get an error with having, `thumb: true` and `class: "ui~~~~"` in the same line. How can I avoid error and still manage to add `class` in image tag?

Comment: can you show the error? are you sure it has to do with slim?

Comment: @maxpleaner thx for the comment! it says "ArgumentError at /
unknown keyword: class"

Answer (score 0):

I think you are losing 'do' after first line.
Try this:

```
= link_to collaborator.user do
  = user_image_of collaborator.user.avatar, thumb: true, class: "ui avatar image carouselCollaboratorsImage"
```

But I dont think it will help. Maybe try:

```
= link_to collaborator.user do
  = user_image_of collaborator.user.avatar, thumb: true, input_html: { class: "ui avatar image carouselCollaboratorsImage" }
```

Btw - What are you using to manage images? If are you using paperclip u can try it with this:

```
= link_to collaborator.user do
  =image_tag collaborator.user.avatar.url(:thumb), class: '...'
```

Or if u are using dragonfly try this

```
= link_to collaborator.user do
  =image_tag collaborator.user.avatar.thumb('100x100#').url, class: '...'
```

The options for defining thumb options u can find here: [ImageMagic Processors Guide](https://markevans.github.io/dragonfly/imagemagick#processors)